# chrome extension native message passing :: Failed to connect: Error when communicating with the native messaging host

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am new to chrome extension native message passing. I have read the document at:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

and the example I am sharing is taken from this only (https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging)

, except that in place of python host, I have a simple java program. On running extension, and clicking on "connect", I am getting error:

Failed to connect: Error when communicating with the native messaging host.

My guess is that this is 2 errors combined:

Failed to Connect

Error when Communicating

As an experiment,  I didnt send any message from java host, expecting that it will not throw "error when communicating error", but still I get the same error message. Below is code:

Chrome Files:

manifest.json:

```
{
  // Extension ID: knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaYhSpDCE9RPocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
  "name": "Native Messaging Example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    //"default_icon": {
    //    "19": "img/icon19.png",
    //    "38": "img/icon38.png"
    //},
    "default_popup": "main.html"
},
"type": "stdio",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ]
}
```

Full extension code can be found at:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/app/main.js

Local Files:

com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json :

```
{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echo",
  "description": "Chrome Native Messaging API Example Host",
  "path": "native-messaging-example-host.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/"
  ]
}
```

install_host.bat

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json" /f
```

native-messaging-example-host.bat:

```
cd C:\Users\jagrati.agrawal\Desktop\servicenow\src-master-chrome-common-extensions-docs-examples-api-nativeMessaging\host && java HelloWorld
```

HelloWorld.java

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String message = "{\"m\":\"hi\"}";
 
System.out.println(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).putInt(message.length()).array());
System.out.write(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.flush();
 
}
}
```

Please help. Also, if I understand right that when I change HelloWorld.java and compile it to get HelloWorld, I don't need to re-install extension.

[chrome extension error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuKBZ.png)

Comment: @wOxxOm : The id is correct.

Comment: Check [the log file](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Comment: @wOxxOm : On windows, from command prompt, I am trying: C:\Users\jagrati.agrawal\Desktop\servicenow\src-master-chrome-common-extensions-docs-examples-api-nativeMessaging\host>C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome --enable-logging=stderr --v=1 > log.txt 2>&1  and then I start the extension and click on connect but log file gets generated but is empty.

Comment: Check `chrome_debug.log` as described in that article.

Comment: @wOxxOm : Even in that file nothing goes.

Comment: Verify you closed the browser completely by using `Exit` command in the browser menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm : After using Exit , logs started coming in command prompt window..thanks a ton!!